# My everything is yours, my mind, my body, my possessions, my life

Tags: possessive-adjectives, metonymy

In a long distance strong close platonic love relationship as mother and son, would the proper English term for this statement be all rights given pertaining to him and his life or is there another to define it properly?

Comment: "My everything" sounds more than platonic to me.

Comment: My question was edited

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about your *property* than you might say

> Everything I **have** is yours.

If you are talking about yourself, you might say

> Everything I **am** is yours.

**Total access** in terms of a person, usually suggests something *sexual*.

The conditions you are using suggest

> complete **openness**
>   complete **submission**

The reason and terms for doing something like that, also have a strong influence on how to describe it, whether it is voluntary or involuntary.

Comment: Absolutely. In short, **you are my everything". :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest statement here is

> I am yours.

There are hundreds of ways to say it.

> All that I am and all that I have is yours.